# C++ can you design a data structure that keeps pointers in contiguous memory and doesn't invalidate them?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, data-structures, syntax

I am trying to implement the half edge data structure for mesh representation. My current hurdle is,

For this DS you need multiple pointers, an example of a possible implementation is this:

```
class HalfEdge {
        Edge * next;
        Edge * prev;
        Edge * pair;
        Vertex * vertex;
        Face * face;
}
```

There's nothing wrong with that. However if you use pointers (let's say we use smart pointers instead of raw to avoid known issues with pointers), your data now lives sparsely in memory and you loose performance due to caching. Worse, if you want to send that mesh to the gpu, now you must serialize the vertices, and imagine you have to do that every frame!

So an alternative is to have arrays and then do this:

```
// Somewhere else we have vectors of edges, faces and vertices
// we store their indices in the array rather than pointers.
class HalfEdge {
        uint next_index;
        uint prev_index;
        uint pair_index;
        uint vertex_index;
        uint face_index;
}
```

This, combined with the arrays, will allow you to keep stuff contingently in memory and now you can send the mesh to the gpu without the overhead of making the linearized buffer. However this has a syntax problem.

Before you could do `face->field` now you have to do `face_array[face_index].field` Which is super clunky.

Naively one could think that combining vertices for allocation and pointers for access would work, something like `Face* face = &face_array[index]`, however, anyone with enough experience in C++ knows that pointer is going to become invalid the second the array is resized.

Not knowing the potential size of the mesh, the array can't be pre allocated, so it's not possible to do that.

Based on all of the above, can you do better than `face_array[index].field` if you want the memory to be contingent?

Comment: That was a fast downvote, could you please provide feedback?

Comment: Do you mean "contiguous" where you have "contingent"?

Comment: Maybe? I mean that the objects are tightly packed in RAM

Comment: I don't see how `face->field` and `face_array` are supposed to relate to the `HalfEdge` changes.

Comment: `face->field` is accessing a field through a pointer

face_array is an array of faces that you access through an index, let me edit the quesiton

Comment: @aschepler Does that comment make it more clear?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to do use `face_array` but have an inline member function to get back a prettier-looking `face().field` (if I understand what you're looking for)? As in, is your question just "I want contiguous memory, but prettier way of accessing it for this structure"?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean by inline member function. 

The goal is to try to avoid having to explicitly specify the index of the element in the array you are accessing, i.e avoid the square bracket semantics.

This can be achieved by doing `auto variable_ptr = &array[index]` and storing `variable_ptr` for future use, but the problem with that is, the second your container is resized the pointers vanish and your variable is now UB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you store your members in a list, you could do something like:

```cpp
class HalfEdge {
public:
  Edge& next() { return (*edge_list)[next_index]; }
  Edge& prev() { return (*edge_list)[prev_index]; }
  // ...
  // probably also const-qualified versions is a good idea

private:
  // or global if needed, or whatever
  std::vector<Edge>* edge_list;
  // ...

  std::size_t next_index;
  std::size_t prev_index;
  // ...
};
```

This will allow you to access values in your local scope like

```cpp
HalfEdge he = /* ... */;
auto& edge = he.next();  // which is otherwise equivalent to
auto& edge = edge_list[he.next_index];
```

In essence it's similar to your idea of storing a reference, but rather than storing a reference to a data member that can get invalidated we instead store a reference to the actual array, and recalulate the offset as needed.

Comment: hmmm, this is pretty cool and quite elegant too. Imma wait a day and see if anyone else has any ideas, but otherwise this may be what I am looking for.